# Kendo UI Grid different templates for column based on its data type

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have such Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Differences)
    .Name("formDifferencesList")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fullScreen" })
    .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(e => e.Property);
                            columns.Bound(e => e.FieldPath);
                            columns.Bound(e => e.FieldType);
                            columns.Bound(e => e.Type);
                            columns.Bound(e => e.LeftValue);
                            columns.Bound(e => e.RightValue);
                        })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Selectable()
    .Resizable(resize =>
        resize.Columns(true))
        .Groupable()
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
            dataSource.Ajax()
            .PageSize(25)
            .ServerOperation(false)
                .Model(model => model.Id(e => string.Format("{0}{1}", e.Property, e.FieldPath)))))
```

`RightValue` and `LeftValue` is instance of type `Object`, it can be primitive value (like `int`, `string`), but also it can be a collection. If it is a collection I want to use Kendo `ListView` to represent it. How should I do that?

I tried to bound to the DataBound event

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDifferencesDataBounded"))
```

added ClientTemplate to the Grid

```
columns.Bound(e => e.LeftValue).ClientTemplate("<div class='leftValueView'></div>");
```

and then inside js function tried to apply the template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDifferencesDataBounded() {
        $.each($('.leftValueView'), function () {
            var grid = $('#formDifferencesList').data().kendoGrid;
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
            $(this).kendoListView({
                dataSource: { data: dataItem },
                template: kendo.template($("#leftValueTemplate").html())
            });
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="leftValueTemplate"> 
    // Not sure what should I do here?
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything at all in the **dataItem.LeftValue** or RightValue such as Array, when you put a breakpoint there?

var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row); // <-breakpoint when you pass that line

If there is array such as number array **[1,3,4,5]** then you can give a try to use **#=data#** inside of the template.